# Float and Height

Tags: css, html, xhtml, css-float

I have a div named footerWrap, which contains 3 unordered lists.
I floated left, all the unordered lists.

My intention was to make the footerWrap grow in height according to the height of the unordered lists. However... in all browsers (exept IE6) the unordered lists pass over the div... like they had z-index atribute!

I tried to place a div at the end, with the clear:all, and i also tried to make float:none on the div#footerWrap

This is my Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is my Full CSS code:

```
div#footerWrap
{
    height:180px;
    background-color:#5c5c5c;
    background-image:url('../../img/bgFooter.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-top:20px;
}



    /* menus footer */
    div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu,
    div#footerWrap ul#myMenu,
    div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu
    {width:180px; float:left;}

        div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu li a,
        div#footerWrap ul#myMenu li a,
        div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li a 
        {
            color:#dadada;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:5px;
        }

            div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu li a,
            div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li a
            {padding:5px 10px;}

            /* hover */
            div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu li a:hover,
            div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li a:hover
            {color:#fff; background-color:#666;}


    /* menu principal */
    div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu {margin-top:-10px;}

        div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu li{line-height:24px;}       

        /* /menu principal */



        /* o meu menu*/
        div#footerWrap ul#myMenu {margin-left:15px;}

            div#footerWrap ul#myMenu li {color:#fff; line-height:22px;}

                    div#footerWrap ul#myMenu li.myMenuItem a 
                    {
                        background-image:url('../../img/smallArrow.gif');
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-position:left 7px;
                        padding-left:15px;
                        padding-right:20px;
                    }

                        div#footerWrap ul#myMenu li.myMenuItem a:hover
                        {color:#fff; background-color:#666;}                
        /* /o meu menu */



        /* outros menu */
        div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu {margin-left:300px; width:340px;}

            div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li 
            {
                color:#fff;
                line-height:22px;
            }

                div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li a{margin-left:5px;}
                div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu li a span {margin-left:-5px;}

        /* /outros menu */
```

And this is my XHTML code:

```
       <div id="footerWrap">

            <!-- menu principal -->
            <ul id="mainMenu">
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>


            <!-- o meu menu -->
            <ul id="myMenu">
                <li>meu menu</li>
                <li class="myMenuItem slideMenuItem"><a href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>


            <!-- outros menu -->
            <ul id="othersMenu">
                <li><span>outros</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `height: 180px;` on `#footerWrap`. Floating the 3 ul's left is good but you need to clear them.

Add `.clear {clear:both;}` to your CSS.
Add `<div class="clear"></div>` before closing the `#footerWrap` div.

You might also try adding `position: relative;` to `#footerWrap` and adding `div#footerWrap ul {display: block;}` to your CSS.

Comment: You are absolutely right!
I added the height atribute just to test the background, before the div had any elements in it, and i totally forgot to remove it later.

Thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try a margin:

```
div#footerWrap ul#mainMenu {margin-left:0}
div#footerWrap ul#myMenu {margin-left:200px}
div#footerWrap ul#othersMenu {margin-left:200px}
```

Actually 180 seems to be enough but the rendering also includes paddings so you need a number greater than 180

Comment: Thx for the answer. But how can margins left help the container div grow in height? I'm not understanding quite well. The problem is not the positioning of the unordered lists, it's the container not growing has i add more items to the unordered lists.